# SSH server routes tunnel by user

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Diagram of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$ sftp joe@gatewayserver.horse

SSHCLIENT_JOE --------> GATEWAY_SERVER (does logic by username to determine  
                             |         socket to forward the connection to.)
                             |
                             \     127.0.0.1:1030 CONTAINRR_SSHD_SALLY
                              ---> 127.0.0.1:1031 CONTAINER_SSHD_JOE
                                   127.0.0.1:1032 CONTAINER_SSHD_MRAYMOND
```

This seems closest to what I'm trying to do:
[paramiko server mode port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579616/paramiko-server-mode-port-forwarding)
http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/11/05/gateway-solutions/

But instead of the client doing a ProxyCommand or requesting a "direct-tcpip" channel, I want the forwarding to be done by the server, invisibly for the client. 
I have been trying to do this with a paramiko server by taking the Transport object of the connecting client and making a direct-tcpip channel on behalf of the client, but I'm running into roadblocks.
I'm Using https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py as a template

```
# There's a ServerInterface class definition that overrides check_channel_request
# (allowing for direct-tcpip and session), and the other expected overides like 
# check_auth_password, etc that I'm leaving out for brevity.

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 2200))
except Exception as e:
    print('*** Bind failed: ' + str(e))
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    sock.listen(100)
    print('Listening for connection ...')
    client, addr = sock.accept()
except Exception as e:
    print('*** Listen/accept failed: ' + str(e))
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)

print('Got a connection!')
try:
    t = paramiko.Transport(client)
    t.add_server_key(host_key)
    server = Server()
    try:
        t.start_server(server=server)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print('*** SSH negotiation failed.')
        sys.exit(1)

   # Waiting for authentication.. returns an unwanted channel object since
   # it isn't the right "kind" of channel
    unwanted_chan = t.accept(20)
    dest_addr = ("127.0.0.1", 1030)       # target container port
    local_addr = ("127.0.0.1", 1234)      # Arbitrary port on gateway server

    # Trying to put words in the client's mouth here.. fails
    # What should I do?
    print(" Attempting creation of direct-tcpip channel on client Transport")
    tunnel_chan = t.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
    print("tunnel_chan created.")
    tunnel_client = SSHClient()
    tunnel_client.load_host_keys(host_key)
    print("attempting connection using tunnel_chan")
    tunnel_client.connect("127.0.0.1", port=1234, sock=tunnel_channel)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = tunnel_client.exec_command('hostname')
    print(stdout.readlines())
except Exception as e:
print('*** Caught exception: ' + str(e.__class__) + ': ' + str(e))
traceback.print_exc()
try:
    t.close()
except:
    pass
sys.exit(1)
```

current output:

```
Read key: bc1112352a682284d04f559b5977fb00
Listening for connection ...
Got a connection!
Auth attempt with key: 5605063f1d81253cddadc77b2a7b0273
Attempting creation of direct-tcpip channel on client Transport
*** Caught exception: <class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException'>: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./para_server.py", line 139, in <module>
tunnel_chan = t.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 740, in open_channel
raise e
ChannelException: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')
```

We currently have a straight-forward sftp server where clients connect and they are chroot-ed to their respective ftp directories. 
We are wanting to move the clients into lxc containers but don't want to alter how they connect to sftp.. (Since they are probably using gui ftp clients like filezilla.) I'm also not wanting to make a bridge interface and assign new ips to all the containers. Thus the containers don't have separate ips from the host, they share the same network space.
The client containers' sshds would bind to separate ports on localhost. That way they can have unique ports, and the logic of which port is chosen could conceptually be moved out to... a simple server on the physical host.

This is more of a proof-of-concept, and general curiosity on my part.

Comment: I don't know paramiko, but just in general, SSH needs to terminate "somewhere", and if your gateway is not the device that negotiates a connection (i.e. you don't want to use ProxyCommand), I would expect you'd need to use NAT to push the TCP connection to another host.

Comment: @ghoti So connecting two channels is not a possibility. I cannot go through 2 sshd's unless the originating client explicitly requests ProxyCommand? It seems to be the wall I'm hitting. I would like to automate the NAT-ing of the ports, though I can only do the logic on that once I get the username of the client. From what I can tell, that is only obtained after a connection negotiation with an sshd. So it's a chicken-and-egg scenario..

Comment: Okay, can't do this in comments, I've provided an answer below.

Comment: I ended up writing a daemon using paramiko that did exactly what I was wanting, which can be found on github [here](https://github.com/mraymond77/ssh_coupler). It only supports sftp at the moment, as that was my immediate need, but I eventually want to add direct ssh shell support as well going forward. It "couples" (for lack of a better term) two authenticated channels together by directly exchanging the payloads of the packets between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, I don't know anything about paramiko, but I can comment on this from an OpenSSH perspective, and perhaps you can translate the concepts to what you need.

NAT was mentioned in comments.  NAT is something done at a lower level than SSH, not something that would be set up on the basis of an SSH login (SOCK5 notwithstanding).  You'd implement it in your firewall, not in your SSH configuration. The way ProxyCommand works is to negotiate the SSH connection, then hand the client to the next hop saying "Here, negotiate with this guy too."  It's something implemented right inside the SSH protocol.

You may not be totally out of luck.

A standard ProxyCommand setup might look like this, with the target port specified on the client side:

```
host joecontainer
    User joe
    ProxyCommand ssh -x -a -q -Wlocalhost:1031 gatewayserver.horse
```

An older fashioned version of this might have used Netcat:

```
host joecontainer
    User joe
    ProxyCommand ssh -x -a -q gatewayserver.horse nc localhost 1031
```

The idea here is that `nc localhost 1031` is the command which provides SSH access to the "next hop" in the SSH chain.  You could run any command here as long as the result of that command is a connection to an SSH daemon.

But you want the port selection to be handled by the GATEWAY rather than by the client.  And therein lies a bit of a crunch, because the SSH daemon is only using the target username to select which user account's authorized_keys file to read.  It's the *keys* which are important, not the user.  By the time the server gets around to running an script or command associated with a user, the SSH negotiation is complete, and it's too late to forward the connection on to the next hop.

So ... you might consider having everyone connect to a *common user*, and then have the port selection done on the basis of *SSH key*.  This is the way, for example, [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#users) handles users.  In your case, Joe and Sally could both connect to `common@gatewayserver.horse` using their DSA or RSA key.

The fun part is that all your port selection gets handled within the "common" user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  The file would look something like this:

```
command="/usr/bin/nc localhost 1030",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ... sally@office
command="/usr/bin/nc localhost 1031",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ... joe@home
```

You can read about this under [the "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" section of the sshd(8) man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS%09FILE_FORMAT).

To use this technique, we still need a client-side ProxyCommand, but because port selection happens server-side based on the client's key, everyone can use exactly the same ProxyCommand:

```
host mycontainer
    ProxyCommand ssh -xaq common@gatewayserver.horse
```

Sally and Joe will run `ssh-keygen` to create a key pair if they haven't already.  They'll send you the public key which you'll add to ~common/.ssh/authorized_keys using the format above.

When Joe connects using his key, the ssh server only runs the `nc` command associated with his key.  And because of the ProxyCommand, that netcat's output is interpreted as a "next hope" for SSH.

I've tested this with sftp (running on my eventual target, akin to your container) and it appears to work for me.

SSH is magic.  :-)

Comment: I didn't know about the authorized_keys command capability. Having a common user would allow me to configure all the proxy-ing server-side and keep things simple for the clients. Thank you for the detailed response!
SSH is magic, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Attempting creation of direct-tcpip channel on client Transport
*** Caught exception: <class '[...]'>: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')
```

The container ssh server is rejecting your direct-tcpip channel request because it has been configured to refuse these requests. I gather the intent here is to proxy SFTP sessions to the correct container? And I imagine the container SSH server has been configured in [the usual fashion](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) to only permit these people to do SFTP? SFTP sessions go through a session channel, not a direct-tcpip channel.

I'm not a python coder and can't give you the specific paramiko code, but your relay agent should open a session channel to the container server and invoke the "sftp" subsystem. And if possible, your relay agent should only do this when the remote client requested an SFTP session, not for other types of channel requests.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that would be a problem once I tried to connect the original client through. It seems the point of failure is before the sftp connection attempt is even made on the container sshd, the script should print "attempting connection using tunnel_chan" before the sftp attempt would be made on the container sshd. Which I now know would fail anyways.